# multiple users not receiving result from Meteor method call - works once, then returns undefined?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-methods

Ok this is an interesting one. I am sorting a list of users in Meteor and trying to return the index number of the user to the client.  i.e. I want the first user created to be position 1, the second user created to be position 2, third user position 3, etc.

I am using a Meteor method on the server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  setPosition: function(userId) {
    let usersArray = Meteor.users.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: 1}}).fetch();
    if (!this.userId) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
    }
    let pos = [];
    for (i = 0; i < usersArray.length; i ++) {
      if (usersArray[i]._id === this.userId) {
         pos = i + 1;
       }
         console.log('this is the position', pos);
         return pos;
     };
    }
  }); //Meteor methods
}//end of meteor isServer
```

The server code above is working perfectly in the terminal EXCEPT the "return pos" line, which makes the code deliver the value to the client for the first user (I see position 1), but break for the subsequent users (res is undefined).  If I remove the "return pos" line, then the code works perfectly on the server for ALL users, *but I cannot get a single result from my Meteor method call on the client*.

This client code below is having trouble receiving the result from the Method call on the server and I don't know why:

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('position');
    Meteor.call('setPosition', Meteor.userId(), (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(err.message);
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(Meteor.userId());
        Session.set('position', res);
      }
    });
});
```

Also, I'm a newb so I apologize for any obvious formatting errors, please point out if you feel the need.   Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just say that this approach is unlikely to scale well as the more users you have the longer it's going to take to find a user's *position* in the list of users.

Assuming that a user's position never changes (i.e. you don't care about deletions - the 4th user is always 4th even if #3 gets deleted), you'd be better off adding a `sequence` key to the user object on user creation. You can look at the sequence number of the most recently created user and increment that by one to give it to the next user. You'll want that key to be indexed of course. Then each user can know their sequence number with just `Meteor.user().sequence`

Comment: Thanks for the that, I hadn't seen the sequence key!  But I do want the code to watch for deletions so that the 4th user would become 3rd if the original 3rd were deleted.  Do you have a way to do that?  I guess scalability is not in my priority yet, but it is on my radar.

Comment: You'd have to resort and re-sequence the whole collection after any deletion if you want to avoid holes.

Comment: Not even need to re-sort, just decrement the `sequence` of all users after the deleted one…